# Exchange 2010 partially offline during Backup (wbadmin)

Tags: backup, exchange, exchange-2010, wbadmin

We have an Exchange Server 2010 on a physical Dell Server (Power Edge R410, 64bit, 32 GB Ram, Windows Server 2008R2 Standard) and every night we make a full-vss backup with the integrated "Windows Server Backup" (wbadmin). The backup takes 5-6 hours and during this time sometimes (not every time) our Clients (mail clients like outlook, smartphones, etcetera) can not connect to the Server (time out). 
I found this Errors in the EventViewer: EventID 1016 and 104. So i decided to reduce the Memory taken from store.exe (ADSIEDIT - msExchESEParamCacheSizeMax), but still the same Problem. 
Does anyone has the same Problem or have any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could this be due to a VSS "freeze"? Do you see Event ID 2027 followed by Event ID 2029 in the Application event log at around the time of the client problems?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to us sometimes, too, and I've always assumed that it's disk contention.  Generally, our email is only unavailable for a matter of minutes, at most.  Without knowing more about your environment it's hard to say, but perhaps your disks are slower than ours.   Also, I'm mainly running incrementals, and don't know if that makes a difference.

I would look into disk health first, to rule that out, and perhaps [the Windows Dynamic Cache service](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9258).